# I can't delete a file - even when using unlocker

Tags: windows-7

Ok, so when I try to delete this from my desktop, I get this error:

[image]

When I click "See what's locking this" in lock hunter, I get this:

[image]

Now, I have a drive, called G:. I only have one physical drive, and it's D:. Also, I have NO virtual drive software installed, so I have NO clue how it got there. Right-clicking on G:\ and chosing eject doesn't do anything but change the logo, it still says the file size and whatnot. Here's the picture of the "What's locking this?" of the contained file:

[image]

But when I try to delete it...

[image]

Both of these files don't let me delete them. I had put win8install.iso as a virtual drive a while back, but I uninstalled that software (but can reinstall it if needed)

Starting this in safe mode doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try rebooting in Safe Mode and deleting it?

Comment: @techie007 that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you mounted the ISO to a virtual CD drive?

Comment: @Indrek no, I don't currently have any virtual CD drives installed.

Comment: Have you run a disk check to rule out file system corruption?

Comment: Check out my [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/440641/deleting-folders-give-access-denied-error-message-on-windows-7-although-i-am-ad/440645#440645) and try **bootdelete** which is a good option.

Comment: Is `Windows8-ReleasePreview-UpgradeAssistant.exe` running? Did you try stopping/killing `Windows8-ReleasePreview-UpgradeAssistant.exe`?

Comment: It isn't running.

Comment: Have you tried the bootdelete which I linked in my answer? What error you got in safe mode?

Comment: @avirk My desktop doesn't appear in safemode for some reason. My background/icons/etc.

Comment: @chipperyman573 : This G drive... is it a shared drive of any sorts or a virtual drive created using the `subst` command in windows?

Comment: @chipperyman573 : Also could you please post a screenshot by trying to unlock using Unlocker x64 in case you haven't done so?

Comment: @chipperyman573: That's already your third post here about this same problem : [post1](http://superuser.com/questions/458789/i-cant-delete-a-file-its-in-use-by-the-system-but-it-isnt) and [post2](http://superuser.com/questions/480588/i-cant-delete-a-shortcut-even-though-both-magic-unlocker-and-lock-hunter-say-n).

Comment: @harrymc For the first one, I forgot about it. For the second, I posted it after then realized that I probably should have just attached a bounty to my first one

Comment: @VrushankDesai Unlocker doesn't error, it just force closes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get a [Linux Live Cd](http://www.livecdlist.com/), and get gparted, systemrescue or parted magic (any release  would work, but a small distro for something quick). Burn it to cd/usb, and boot your computer to it. Mount the hd, and find the folder and delete it.

You can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the live cd or do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to identify which process is keeping an open handle to the file.

1. Click `Find > Find Handle or DLL...`
2. Enter `win8image.iso`
3. Click `Search`

Then make the program close its handle. In your case the issue might be that the ISO image is still connected to a virtual machine or a virtual drive.

Comment: This is what I get after I click search and it searches: http://i.imgur.com/B0Nqo.png

Comment: @chipperyman573 Did you run Process Explorer "as Administrator"?

Comment: This is what I get when I run it with UAC: http://i.imgur.com/As73k.png

Comment: This is PID 4: http://i.imgur.com/T9tV7.png

Comment: Like I said, I strongly suspect that the image is still connected to some virtual machine or drive.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have no virtual machine installed.

Comment: Strange. You said you have UAC enabled. Can you delete the file when you *disable* UAC? Also, when you run `Process Explorer` "as Administrator", display the lower pane (`View > Show Lower Pane`) and search for the handle again, can you manually close the handle (right click > `Close Handle`)?

Comment: @chipperyman573, `System` means that it is loaded via a driver. You may not have it *mounted* as a drive-letter, but it is *open* with some sort of mounting program’s driver.

Comment: @Synetech I don't have ANY mounting drivers installed. I spent two hours last night researching every driver I had installed - none of them mounted virtual drives.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I disabled UAC, still didn't work.

Comment: @Synetech, Hmm, how did you know that "`System` means that it is loaded via a driver"?

Answer (score 3):

If none software is doing the job then you can use the **OLD IS GOLD** formula and that is command prompt. If you want to delete the file from the running Windows then open the **elevated-command prompt**(*command prompt window with admin rights*). For this click on the *start* menu and then type `CMD` in search box and right click on the `cmd.exe` and then click on the option **Run as Administrator**.

Now open the Windows explorer and click on the *`Organize`* > *`Folder and Search Option`*.

[image]

Now unchecked the option **Hide extension for known file types** and click **OK**. And go to method **1** or **2**.

[image]

## To Use a Command Prompt at Boot

a. [To Use a Command Prompt at Boot](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/682-command-prompt-startup.html)

b. In the command prompt, type **diskpart** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

c. In the command prompt, type **list volume** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

d. After making note of the drive letter, type **exit** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Method 1**

### To Delete a Specific File in Command Prompt

In the command prompt, type the command below and press enter.

> DEL /F /S /Q /A "Full Path of File with extension"

Example

> DEL /F /S /Q /A "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\File.txt"

File should be deleted now.

**Method 2**.

### To Delete All Files in a Folder without Confirmation in Command Prompt

In the command prompt, type the command below and press enter.

> DEL /F /S /Q /A "Full Path of Folder*"

File should be deleted now.

Close the command prompt.

**NOTE:** If you used a command prompt at boot, then also close the System Recovery Options window and restart the computer.

For more information you can check out this [Sevenforum article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/55728-file-delete-command-prompt.html).

Comment: With the first method: http://i.imgur.com/OLUQs.png. As for the second method, I don't want to delete my desktop.

Comment: Did you tried the command prompt in safe mode? Also try the command prompt at the boot time and try to delete the file. I have given the link in my answer that [how to open command prompt at boot time](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/682-command-prompt-startup.html) for that you just need a Windows 7 repair/installation disc.

Comment: Also have you tried bootdelete to delete the file?

Comment: Yes. Still didn't work.

Comment: What happened when you tried to command prompt at boot time?

Comment: It just crashed.

Comment: Command prompt crashed or you talking about the bootdelete? If none is working then linux live cd will help you, which you don't need to install just put it the drive and play it and it will let you delete this stuff.

Comment: this didnt work for me either.  folder contains a folder called `ModifiableWindowsApps`, cant delete either.  i was able to rename the parent folder, i keep it named `del` as a reminder.

Comment: @BrianThomas you tried with unlocker or not?

Comment: Yes, unlocker fails

Answer (score 2):

Windows includes the ability to mark files for deletion upon reboot. This ensures the files are not in use at the time as they are deleted by the system before Windows starts completely.

<strike>An application [such as this one](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Remove-on-Reboot-Shell-Extension-Download-11973.html) exposes this functionality to the end user.</strike>

Edit: I would recommend [MoveFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556) as it is from a reputable source (Thanks Ansgar).

Comment: Another option would be Sysinternals' [MoveFiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556).

Comment: Of course, I had forgotten about this one.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend deleting the file like that willy-nilly. If something is using it, then by deleting it, you may break something (that could end up crashing the whole system). It is better to find out *where/what* is locking it and stop that.

Answer (score 2):

[Take ownership](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx) of the ISO file and then delete it. This happens sometimes on my Win7 x64 as well.

You may also want to consider [adding this option in the right-click menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) so you can take ownership of any NEW file before you start working with it.

On a side note, Unlocker now has a [64-bit](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#download) version too.. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning 64-bit version, most of the user's install the 32-bit version and puzzled on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I'm already the owner of the file and I can't delete it.

Comment: @chipperyman573, you may be the owner, but you also need permissions (permission ***s***, not permission). Use the security tab to add write/delete permissions for your user account to the file’s ACL (access control list).

Comment: I have all of them

Comment: You need permissions for `Windows8-ReleasePreview-UpgradeAssistant.exe`, the ISO file is locked because it’s open (two different casues of locked files).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that win8install.iso is mounted as a virtual drive in Windows.
Since Windows 8, any .iso can be mounted natively without the need for third-party software.

You can find a description of the process in [How to Mount or Unmount ISO images in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/1697-iso-images-mount-unmount.html).

You can verify whether this is the case by calling Windows Explorer :

[image]

Comment: I've already tried this. Plus, win8 is installed on a virtual machine (I never actually installed the one in my drive), which is now deleted.

Comment: Well, if this VM is now dead, then no more problems.

Comment: Except for the stuck icon.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. You might add to your post what you see when you right-click the icon and select Properties.