# I can't delete a shortcut, even though both Magic Unlocker and Lock Hunter say nothing's locking it

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't delete a file - even when using unlocker](https://superuser.com/questions/469683/i-cant-delete-a-file-even-when-using-unlocker)

Ok, so when I try to delete this from my desktop, I get this error:

[image: Windows Explorer Error]

When I click "See what's locking this" in lock hunter, I get this:

[image: LockHunter File Info]

Now, I have a drive, called G:. I only have one physical drive, and it's D:. Also, I have NO virtual drive software installed, so I have NO clue how it got there. Right-clicking on G:\ and choosing eject doesn't do anything but change the logo, it still says the file size and whatnot. Here's the picture of the "What's locking this?" of the contained file:

[image: LockHunter Diagnostics]

But when I try to delete it...

[image: Deletion error with filelock]

Both of these files don't let me delete them. I had put win8install.iso as a virtual drive a while back, but I uninstalled that software (but can reinstall it if needed)

Additionally, I previously made a post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/469683/i-cant-delete-a-file-even-when-using-unlocker) about this, however I now have more information about this (I hadn't noticed the G:\ drive and a few other things), and wasn't sure if I should bump up such an old post by editing it or making another post. **If I should have just edited the old one, please don't get mad - I didn't know. Just close this and let me know, I'll edit the old one and attach a bounty.** If not, please take a look at the answers already posted there, none of them worked (sadly)

Comment: when you type “compmgmt.msc” into search and type it, what do you see under disk management?

Comment: @AlanTuring I see this: http://i.imgur.com/EAMKC.png

Comment: Have you tried deleting it while in Safe Mode?

Comment: @Karan that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use an Ubuntu live CD, navigate to your desktop folder and then delete it?

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu live CD. I've never installed Ubuntu on this machine.

Comment: Well, the whole point of a LiveCD is that you run it from the CD. No need to install anything.  If you do not like Ubuntu you could use ERD commander (a windows based liveCD).