# Unable to stop chrome.exe *32

Tags: windows, google-chrome, tasks

So I was installing roboform today and was unable to stop the process chrome.exe *32... Even when I uninstalled chrome. This is the error I got:

[image: This is the error I got]

I used lockhunter and it said it was located in %appdata%\Local\Google\Chrome. However, it was unable to unlock, delete or rename. When I use explorer to delete or rename that folder, it says it's being used by Chrome. Even after restarting my computer it still does this. I've tried using the built in chrome task manager (Wrench > View Background Pages) and I can't seem to find a process there that has the same amount of memory.

I have run many, many virus scans, by:

- Microsoft security essentials
- AVG (Free version)
- Malwarebytes (Pro version)
- Norton 360 (Pro version)
- McAfee (Pro Version)
- Avira (Free version)
- Avast! Antivirus (Free version)

None of which returned with any viruses.

Chrome info:

Google Chrome       23.0.1271.95 (Official Build 169798)

OS        Windows 7 Professional

WebKit        537.11 (@135931)

JavaScript        V8 3.13.7.5

Flash        11.5.31.2

User Agent        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11

Comment: I sure hope you don't have all those antivirus programs installed at once...

Comment: No, I didn't. I installed one, uninstalled it, installed another, etc. I'm not _that_ stupid...

Comment: Do you think this has to do with the permissions you have or just a really stubborn file?

Comment: @ChristopherChipps I checked the folder owner/etc, I'm the owner and have full permissions.

Comment: Are you able to delete it from within Safe Mode?

Comment: @Sam Nope. If it helps I have a related issue [here](http://superuser.com/questions/469683/i-cant-delete-a-file-even-when-using-unlocker). It's the same thing, except that process isn't a running process, just a shortcut. Other than that it's the same.

Comment: Is this a shared computer? You've been able or unable to locate it in processes in task manager?

Comment: @ChristopherChipps No, it's my computer. I'm an admin, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a live Ubuntu( or other distro) Usb stick . Go to Ubuntu.com if you don't know how to do this .

Boot off the Usb stick , and while in Ubuntu delete the Chrome.exe  . 
Delete your entire temp folder too .

Note : You run the risk of breaking other things too ,I'm not sure what Roboform modifies though . Alternatively go into MSConfig and revoke Chrome's permission to run on startup .

Comment: I rec'd using Linux Live as a USB creator for Ubuntu.