# Windows 7 locked out of program files

Tags: windows-7, permissions, virus

I while ago my computer crashed and a file in my virus protector got lost in the recovery process. Because of this, I cannot uninstall, reinstall, or install a newer version of the virus protector. I've figured out what file went missing, and have downloaded the file. But when I try to move the file into the virus protectors folder, it says I need administrator permission it do it. I've seen things about changing permissions by going to properties-security-advanced, but even when I do that it just says access denied when it gets to the program files.

Any ideas on how to get into this folder so I can replace the lost file, uninstall the current virus protector, and install the new virus protector?

The file that is missing is rtl120.bpl

Comment: So you have taken ownership of the folder, and despite that, you cannot place a file in that folder?  If thats the case then your Windows installation is corrupt and should be replaced.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/469683/i-cant-delete-a-file-even-when-using-unlocker/469698#469698  You can copy \ replace any file as well delete any file using a linux live cd. Btw, "rtl120.bpl" is a run time dll for Delphi 2009 compiler. There are hundreds of applications that use the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you tried this, but just making it explicit:

- In windows explorer, go to your program files directory
- Right-click on the anti-virus folder and select "properties"
- Go to the Security tab
- click the "Edit" button
- Click "Users" in the top list
- click "full control" in the lower list
- click OK

Can you then replace the file?

If no, then maybe try clicking the "Add..." button and writing "everyone" in the text box, click "Check Names" (it should then capitalize and underline "Everyone" to show that it found it) and click OK, then set Full Control on that and hopefully that works.

Undo whatever access changes you made when you're done, to protect the folder.