# How to rename folder? Folder in use

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting folders give access denied error message on Windows 7, although I am administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/440641/deleting-folders-give-access-denied-error-message-on-windows-7-although-i-am-ad)

I am trying to rename a folder, but apparently it is in use. I don't think it is. I'd like to rename my folder. How can I do that?

This happens regularly, and at random, particularly in my music folder. I'd like to know the cause and fix that. Rather than workaround with some special tool whenever I want to rename a file.

[image]

Comment: Reboot and try again.

Comment: You can try [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/). For more Information see my this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/440645/86550), however its about delete a folder but it can also rename the folder by unlocking its process.

Comment: If Windows tells you that the folder is in use, then it is, even if you think it isn't. From the screenshot it looks like you might have video files in there, so it may well be a case of Explorer parsing the files to generate thumbnails.

Comment: If its not a very large file and if your HD can afford having a copy,
Just **copy** that folder and then you will be able **Rename** it.

Comment: This happens often, but unpredictably. I want to know WHY and fix the cause, not just workaround it once.

Answer (score 0):

same as @avirk suggested, use [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/). It terminates the process which keeps the file in use and let you rename, move or delete any file or folder.